# SQL Server on delete trigger not doing what I expect it to do

Tags: sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

Trigger should fire when deleting a dish. All orders containing this dish are going to be deleted.

So far, I've got this script:

```
create trigger OnDishDeleted 
on Dish 
after delete as 
begin 
    delete from Dish_Order 
    where Dish_ID = (select Dish_ID from deleted) 
end
```

When I try to delete a dish, I get an error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Dish_Order_Dish". The conflict occurred in database "davay_rabotai2", table "dbo.Dish_Order", column 'Dish_ID'.

ER diagram:

[Click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abRFd.png)

Comment: Why not turn on cascading delete on the foreign key instead? If you want to do this via trigger, you have to *remove* the FK, because constraints checks happen well before this trigger fires.

Comment: This trigger assumes that only 1 row will ever be deleted at a time (if more than one is, then it'll give an error about the subquery having more than 1 row). But @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, Cascade delete would seem the far simpler solution over a trigger.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the problem here is that this is my task at university. I should do it by using triggers. Is there any other ways to remake this ER diagram?

Comment: @Kas make your trigger not `after delete`, but `instead of delete`. Then delete from Dish_Order first, and then delete the row(s) from Dish table.

Comment: OMG when are they going to stop teaching useless triggers at university. Triggers are a last resort!!

Answer (score 0):

Use an `instead of` trigger if you need to delete rows in another table first.
This is an example that can get you started.

```
CREATE trigger OnDishDeleted on dbo.Dish
instead of delete 
as
begin
     set nocount on

     delete from Dish_Order where Dish_ID in (select Dish_ID from deleted) 
     delete from Dish where Dish_ID in (select Dish_ID from deleted) 
end
```

The difference with a normal trigger is that you also need to delete the rows from the table `Dish` yourself in this trigger.
An `instead of` trigger does not deletes anything, it just fires when the delete statement is given and you have to do all the work yourself.

More info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
and
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/def01zh2.aspx

Also notice that I use `IN` in stead of `=` for the where clause, this is because `deleted` in a trigger can have more than one row. That is another flaw in your trigger code. Always assume there can be more then one row in triggers.

That said, your solution has another problem.
From your ER diagram i see you also have payments and other rows stored in other tables that are linked to a dish.  You also need to delete these rows.
But deleting payments is not something I would like to see happening in my database.
Are you sure this is what you want to do ?